# Issue with reading of Appointment Attendees with using Redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

Using redemption library we are reading appointment.
While reading we encountered an exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
at Redemption.ISafeAppointmentItem.get_OptionalAttendees()
```

Can anyone advise what might be causing the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: When and where do you get that exception in the code?